# dynamic addition usercontrol to tablelayout

Tags: c#, winforms

For example i have such usercontrol.
I want to dynamically add this to known field(tablelayout6).
How do i need to edit this usercontrol to fulfill my goal? I don't know how refer to my tablelayout.

```
public class Userblock : UserControl
{
    TextBox textName;
    Label labelName;
    cCheckedListBox listtablelayout6;

    public Userblock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        textName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        labelName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        labelName.Text = "Name:";
        listtablelayout6.Size =  new System.Drawing.Size(112, 100);
        Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[]
        {
            labelName,
            labelAddress,
            listtablelayout6
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "How do i need to edit this usercontrol to fulfill my goal? I don't know how refer to my tablelayout."  Generally speaking, you don't. The UserControl presumably gets created by the FORM. In code, at the Form level, you can refer to both the UserControl and the TableLayoutPanel, so that's where you'd link them. If you want to add from **within** the UserControl, then create a Constructor overload that receives a reference to the TableLayoutPanel. Store that reference in the UserControl so you can use it later in the code. You'd pass the reference when you create the UserControl with "new".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy..

```
yourTableLayoutName.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "I'm a Button" });
yourTableLayoutName.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "I'm a Label" });
```

Your can put properties of controls inside `{ }`

Comment: Userblock ttt = new Userblock();
tableLayoutPanel6.Controls.Add(ttt); When i try to use this nothing works.

Comment: I did it first,but controls redrawn after adding each new item. when you create several such blocks it takes a lot of time and looks ugly.I was advised to do usercontrol to reduce redraws.